# DNS caching using DDoS protection services

Tags: networking, dns

I'm currently using CloudFlare's services for my domain.

The interesting thing is that when I change my A record, the new website popup after a few minutes.

I remember, when I didn't used them, I had to wait 24 hours, and even 48 hours on some computers.

Is this because of them? If it is, I guess it's because I change the A record, but the domain actually remains with the same (theirs)?

Comment: Related Q&A from ServerFault: [Is low TTL an appreciable burden on DNS?](http://serverfault.com/a/584445/39085).

Comment: But what if they don't change the A record, when I change it using the control panel? Then, there wouldn't be any caching problems. And I think this is the case. I've just sent them an enquiry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every DNS record has a "Time To Live" (aka TTL) which specifies how long dns resolvers should remember an answer before they go get a fresh copy of the answer.

For example:

```
dig +noall +answer stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.com.      144     IN      A       104.16.37.249
stackoverflow.com.      144     IN      A       104.16.35.249
stackoverflow.com.      144     IN      A       104.16.33.249
stackoverflow.com.      144     IN      A       104.16.36.249
stackoverflow.com.      144     IN      A       104.16.34.249
```

In this case, my resolver will remember this answer to the question "stackoverflow.com" for 144 more seconds.  Probably CloudFlare is using a smaller TTL than wherever your DNS records used to come from.

Comment: CloudFlare's TTL is 5 minutes by default, thus propagation is almost immediate, but intermediary resolvers (and browsers) may cache longer - not respecting the original TTL - so its boils down to which server(s) the client uses to resolve the domain, which browsers, and sometimes which operating system.

Comment: If it depends only on TTL, does that mean, that my old DNS server had 86400? I don't remember it that way. Can this issue be connected with the end-user DNS servers?

Comment: Exactly. So the main question is - does CloudFlare change it's records, when I change them using the control panel? Because if they don't - there wouldn't be any cash refresh issues.

Comment: @TurboHost I have no way of knowing what TTL your old server used, but 86400 is not an unusual value.  I presume CloudFlare changes the records in their (authoritative) DNS servers in response to your requests, but other DNS servers may still remember the old values until their records "time out".  And as is pointed out above, there definitely are programs (e.g. web browsers) out there that don't honor TTL -- you lookup something once and may remember it as long as until they are restarted.